# endturnwithnextparticipants, how does it work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I am making a **turnbased game** for iOS with game center, 2 participants per match. I would like to implement a time limit on every turn, so that a player don't have to wait forever for the other player to finish its turn. I have tried:

```
currentMatch endTurnWithNextParticipants:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:nextParticipant,nil] turnTimeout:GKTurnTimeoutDefault matchData:data completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
```

but nothing happens, the player still has forever to do their turn, so I am obviously missing something here.

What happens when the time limit is reached? How does `gamecenter` handle this, and where should I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method updates the data stored on Game Center for the current match.

According to Apple Docs:

*If the next player to act does not take their turn in the specified interval, the next player in the array receives a notification to act. This process continues until a player takes a turn or the last player in the list is notified.
When this method is called, it creates a new background task to handle the request. The method then returns control to your game. Later, when the task is complete, Game Kit calls your completion handler. Keep in mind that the completion handler may be called on a thread other than the one originally used to invoke the method. This means that the code in your block needs to be thread-safe.*

I think you need to also end the players go on their end programatically.

Comment: Do you have an example to do this probably? Or could I have the link to the page? :)

Comment: I got it working :) thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @user2747112 How did you get it to work? Would you mind sharing?